# $\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)|^p< \infty = \int_0^\infty pt^{p-1}\mu (\{x\in \mathbb R:|f(x)| >t \}) dt $

Tags: measure-theory

Let, $p\geq 1$ and $f$ be a Lebesgue measurable function $\mathbb R$ such that
$\int_{\mathbb R}| f(x)|^p< \infty$ show that $\int_{\mathbb R}| f(x)|^p \ dx   = \int_0^\infty pt^{p-1}\mu (\{x\in \mathbb R:|f(x)| >t\} \ dt  $.

My attempts:

Since $f$ is measurable so $A=\{x\in \mathbb R:|f(x)| >t\}$ is measurable. So, $\chi_A(x)$ is measurable.

Now, $\int_0^\infty pt^{p-1}\mu (\{x\in \mathbb R:| f(x)| >t\}) \ dt= \int_0^\infty \int_{\mathbb R}(\chi_A(x)\ dx) \ pt^{p-1} \ dt $

Now I am stuck. Can anyone please help me to proceed?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, this I got. But now how to proceed?

Comment: Don't use `\mid` for absolute values. Just use `|`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x)|^p\,\mathrm d x&=\int_{\mathbb R}\int_0^\infty \boldsymbol 1_{\{y:|f(x)>y|\}}py^{p-1}\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\\
&\underset{\text{Fubini}}{=}\int_0^\infty py^{p-1}\int_{\mathbb R}\boldsymbol 1_{\{x:|f(x)|>y\}}\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y\\
&=...
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your hints @Surb.